# When can I omit the subject?

Tags: grammar, writing-style, writing, subjects, omissibility

Can I omit the subject if it has been mentioned in a preceding sentence?

For example, is the phrase inside the parentheses necessary in the below?:

> > The sculpture A exhibits degradation at a seemingly increased rate from 30 years ago. However, the surrounding environment is considered not to have changed at a significant level since (the sculpture was) carved.

Comment: Your sentence, as it stands, means that the environment was carved. Which is not what you wanted to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word: no. You have to have a pronoun or other noun here: “since it was carved”. You can usually omit the subject in the context “Subject predicate and predicate” (e.g., “Sculpture A exhibits degradation and is a cause for concern”), but adjuncts do not permit this kind of subject omission (e.g., you can’t say “Sculpture A exhibits degradation because _ was poorly conserved / since _ was moved / etc.”).

Also, I wouldn’t use the definite article at the start of the first sentence: “Sculpture A exhibits degradation …”.

Comment: Or 'since being carved' where the pronoun is not involved.

Comment: I have one more question actually. Why repeating the subject or pronoun is unnecessary when I say 'since being carved' there?

Comment: Gerunds like “since being carved” / “since having been carved” pick up a nearby subject. In the current context, it wrongly picks up “the surrounding environment” as its subject, not “sculpture A” from the previous sentence. I wouldn’t use it here.